# ComboBox + VirtualizingStackPanel width bug?

Tags: silverlight, combobox, silverlight-5.0

We're experiencing a problem in our Silverlight app when using a ComboBox along with a VirtualizingStackPanel.  The issue arises when the width of a ComboBox item is significantly wider than the control itself AND when the item is only visible after scrolling (i.e. not visible on load).  With a reasonably long list of items the ComboBox scrolling goes crazy.

Doing some Googling around I can see only one comment describing what we're experiencing but no resolution that I can find.  This appears to be a bug but perhaps we're either doing something wrong or there is a work around.  The markup is simple and roughly looks like the following

```html
<ComboBox>
  <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

By the way, the ComboBoxItems are simple text.  No graphics or other objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same issue, and ended up needing to define an item template for the combo box, and force the width of the item to match the width of an outside column width. This makes the text wrap to multiple lines, but you could change it to use `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"` to trim the text item.

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    ...
    <ColumnDefinition Width="..." x:Name="cbColumn" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=cbColumn}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

In my case, I don't always know what size the combobox will need to be, so that's why I use the binding to a grid column. It may work just as fine to set the width directly in the item template, if you know what size you want the combo box to be.

Comment: By the way, some found the TextWrap and WordEllipsis unacceptable.  As an alternative solution I create a class that derives from ComboBox and overrode the GetContainerForItemOverride() method.  From there I had access to the ItemCollection and was able to determine the best width to use based on the "widest" item.  I then set the ComboBoxItem obtained calling base.GetContainerForItemOverride() then setting the ComboxItem.Width to the determined value.  So, basically, all the ComboBoxItems have the same width which prevents the ScrollViewer from going bonkers.